# Selenium IDE - can I give it input at the start?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have 2 environments - test and production.  The only thing that is different is the base URL.  All other aspects should be identical - objects, pages, etc.

What I am looking to do is to create the option in Selenium to tell it which environment I am looking to test when I click start.  I don't have an issue doing the coding to get it to know which base URL to use once the testing starts, but I am not sure if I can or how I can, make Selenium ask me which environment to use.  For example, I would click start and a pop-up would appear with a drop down showing test or production.

Is something like that possible?  I hate to create two entirely separate tests and test suites just because of the base URL.

Thanks,

Jamie

Comment: How about you set up an environment variable with the URL in it and access it in your code...